# How to merge multiple cod files into single cod file in blackberry apps.?

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to implement multiple cod files into single cod file in blackberry apps.I checked many sites but i didnt get required answer.

Comment: This is done automatically. When the executable package exceeds a certain size, the compiler chunks it in several sibling cod files, and packages them in a parent cod file (which is actually a zip file).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?
If you want to include 3d party libs in your project, and end up with a single COD file (or set of COD files), this can be done in eclipse like so:

1. add JAR file to build path
2. on the "Order and Export" tab of the build path dialog, make sure the JAR file is ticked.

This assumes the jar file you are including had been correctly compiled and pre-verified.
[bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) might be usefull.